# 100 Continue with Jersey2+ with Jetty9+

Tags: java, jetty, jersey-2.0, jetty-9

I am seeing my jersey+jetty server to respond to a 100 continue header before the request is passed on to my handler. I do not want to send a 100-Continue and rather send a 3xx response based on the URI/Headers of the request.

This is the class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent which calls into request.getInputStream()

```
 public Value<Integer> service(
        final URI baseUri,
        final URI requestUri,
        final HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
        final HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {

    ContainerRequest requestContext = new ContainerRequest(baseUri, requestUri,
            servletRequest.getMethod(), getSecurityContext(servletRequest), new ServletPropertiesDelegate(servletRequest));
    requestContext.setEntityStream(servletRequest.getInputStream());
    addRequestHeaders(servletRequest, requestContext);
```

and Jetty sends the 100 Continue header when the input stream on the request is asked for. From org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request

```
@Override
public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException
{
    if (_inputState != __NONE && _inputState != _STREAM)
        throw new IllegalStateException("READER");
    _inputState = _STREAM;

    if (_channel.isExpecting100Continue())
        _channel.continue100(_input.available());

    return _input;
}
```

it calls into the HttpChannel to send the 100 Continue header

```
 /**
 * If the associated response has the Expect header set to 100 Continue,
 * then accessing the input stream indicates that the handler/servlet
 * is ready for the request body and thus a 100 Continue response is sent.
 *
 * @throws IOException if the InputStream cannot be created
 */
public void continue100(int available) throws IOException
{
    // If the client is expecting 100 CONTINUE, then send it now.
    // TODO: consider using an AtomicBoolean ?
    if (isExpecting100Continue())
    {
        _expect100Continue = false;

        // is content missing?
        if (available == 0)
        {
            if (_response.isCommitted())
                throw new IOException("Committed before 100 Continues");

            // TODO: break this dependency with HttpGenerator
            boolean committed = sendResponse(HttpGenerator.CONTINUE_100_INFO, null, false);
            if (!committed)
                throw new IOException("Concurrent commit while trying to send 100-Continue");
        }
    }
}
```

How do I prevent jersey+jetty from sending back the 100 continue till the request reaches the jersey tagged URI path methods?

Answer (score 2):

With `Expect: 100-Continue` processing..

If you want to respond that part of the request, then:

- Don't attempt access to the request parameters (this needs to read the input stream to process all possible parameter sources)
- Don't attempt access to the request input stream (this means you are accepting the `100-Continue` Expectation and are ready to receive the actual request body content)
- Don't attempt access to the request reader (this opens the request input stream too)
- Don't attempt to use the servlet Async I/O layer (this opens the request inputstream and response outputstreams)
- Do use the HttpServletResponse to send your alternate status code and/or response body content.

This is all standard Servlet / Jetty behavior.

Comment: Agreed. But this does not answer my question. 

I get that those are the requirements at Jetty layer. But since the getInputStream() method is called by Jersey before the code gets to any of my code, does it mean that Jersey+Jetty combo does not correctly implement 100 continue?

Comment: Reread the question. I guess I answered only half the question, the Jetty side.  The problem isn't on the Jetty side, its the Jersey assumption that it doesn't have to deal with alternate handling of `100-Continue` expectations.

Comment: The question is for using Jetty+Jersey together. I get your point that this is how Jetty works by itself and yes 100 Continue support is correctly implemented. However, when using Jetty as a container with Jersey, it is broken. The question was to make jersey+jetty combo to use 100 continue successfully, which isn't answered here

Comment: I am running into this exact issue. Did you find any way to get around it?